# How to have ag ignore files with certain extensions (e.g. *.dtd) normally looked at for a given option such as --xml?

Tags: ag

Ag works fine most of the time.  But sometimes, I want to do a search in, say, all XML files by using --xml, but not any .dtd files. Unfortunately, ag looks at .dtd files when asked to examine --xml.

I tried as a wild guess  ag --no-dtd.  Doesn't work.  The --ignore options aren't for this.

I know there's a ~/.agignore file, but being absent minded and often interrupted, I don't want to bother edit that for just one or two searches and have to remember to put it back.  I'm looking for a one-off easy way to avoid a certian file type.
Other examples could be wanting to look at C++ files but wanting to see only .c, .cpp, .cxx and such but not .h or .hpp, for just one time.

Answer (score 2):

Two approaches.

1. Use the file extension (-G) to limit the scope of what ag looks at. For example, if you just want to search xml files: `ag -G '\.xml$' search_token`
2. Roll your own new file type.
   Download the source and modify the `/src/lang.c` file to include your own file types, then (re)compile. Instructions to download and build ag are kept here: https://gist.github.com/k-takata/5124445; sounds like a hassle, but it's easy and fast to do.

Note: BTW, .agignore has been renamed to just .ignore.